# javascript form submit event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, post, event-handling, form-submit

I have user-registration page and want to sent ajax to another page before register starts.
I handle form submit event with 'on' but registration doesn't work at now. After submit form just refreshing my page. And send nothing to register module.

Here is my code

```
function subdomainSent() {
    var subdomain = $('#subdomain').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/module/nmo/display',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'subdomain_check',
            subdomain: subdomain
        },
        success: function (output) {
            alert(output);
            subdomain_complete();
        }
    });
}

function subdomain_complete() {
    document.main_form.submit();
}
$('#account-creation_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    subdomainSent();
});
if (getUrlParameter("action") == "create_account") {
    $("#account-creation_form").attr("action", "http://" + document.domain + window.location.pathname + "?action=create_account");
    $('#submitAccount').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#subdomain_show').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $("#account-creation_form").attr("action", "http://" + document.domain + window.location.pathname);
}
```

And form

```
<form name="main_form" action="" method="post" id="account-creation_form" class="std box">
```

**Update:**
used solution by @Branimir Đurek and
improved my code like this

```
if(start)
{
    var subdomain = $('#subdomain').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/module/nmo/display',
            type: 'post',
            data: {action: 'subdomain_check', subdomain: subdomain},
            success: function(output) {
                start = false;
            }
        });
}
else if(!start)
{
    subdomain_complete();
}
```

and all works at now.

Comment: Is the code wrapped within `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: What error it showing in console

Comment: $(document).ready() - yes, no error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
function subdomain_complete() {
    document.main_form.submit();
}
```

with

```
 function subdomain_complete() {
        $("#account-creation_form").submit();
    }
```

Comment: strange, sending too many ajaxes and throw error 'too many recursion' in console

Comment: That happens because your ajax call is recursive. On every ajax call your function subdomain_complete() is being executed which submit form. It's something like infinite loop. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Oh, thanks guy! changed code like this    var start = true; if !start then not ajax and all works

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are trying to do two different things when submitting your form.
that if conditions should be in $(document).ready() function,
and all functions should be outside doc ready,

your code is like a recursion. so just change it like as follows,

```
 function subdomainSent() {
        var subdomain = $('#subdomain').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/module/nmo/display',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'subdomain_check',
                subdomain: subdomain
            },
            success: function (output) {
                alert(output);
                subdomain_complete();
            }
        });
    }

    function subdomain_complete() {
        $("#account-creation_form).submit();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

$('#account-creation_form_save_btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        subdomainSent();
    });


        if (getUrlParameter("action") == "create_account") {
            $("#account-creation_form").attr("action", "http://" + document.domain + window.location.pathname + "?action=create_account");
            $('#submitAccount').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#subdomain_show').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $("#account-creation_form").attr("action", "http://" + document.domain + window.location.pathname);
        }
});

<form id="account-creation_form">
<!-- your code here -->
<input type="button" id="account-creation_form_save_btn">
</form>
```

here account-creation_form_save_btn is the id of a button which u have to click to submit the form and the button type should not be submit.